# set style for a bunch of labels in javafx

Tags: javafx

i would like to set font size for many labels and possibly without the use of external css file.

I tried using Group and setStyle, but it didn't work. 
(I know how to set style for a label, but not a class of labels)

```
Group label_group = new Group();
Label lb1 = new Label("1");
Label lb2 = new Label("2");
label_group.getChildren().addAll(lb1, lb2);
label_group.setStyle("-fx-font-size:20");
Label lb1 = new Label("1");
Label lb2 = new Label("2");
label_group.getChildren().addAll(lb1, lb2);
label_group.setStyle("-fx-font-size:20");
```

The font size of both labels dont change to 20. How do I define a property for 10 labels ? I'm not sure on how to use external CSS file also, if its the only way.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue. Voting for close, since it's not including a [mcve]. (Your code would not compile, even if inserted to a suitable location btw: you declare multiple variables sharing the same name. Even fixing this issue my the code ***is*** working for me.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a number of `Node` objects to share the same style (without an external CSS stylesheet), just use a simple method that accepts an indefinite number of arguments (called "varargs" in Java, for "variable arguments") to apply them:

```
private void setStyle(Node... nodes) {
    for (Node node : nodes) {
        node.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 20");
    }
}
```

Then you can call the method, passing all of your labels at once:

```
setStyle(lb1, lb2, lb3);
```

Comment: I don't know so I ask, wouldn't it be better to (anyway) define external CSS file?

Comment: @OrdinaryDraft - I wouldn't say either way is *better* than the other. Depends on your needs, complexity, and readability of your code. In either case, the OP asked how to do so specifically without using external CSS :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're interesting in learning how to do it with CSS, you could have the following CSS file called "myStyle.css" in your project's resource directory

```
.label{
    -fx-font-size:20
}
```

and then in your java code

```
Label lb1 = new Label("1");
Label lb2 = new Label("2"); 
scene.getStylesheets().add(yourClassName.class.getResource("myStyle.css").toExternalForm());
```

where scene is whatever scene you are putting your labels in (you can also use stage.getScene() if you need). All of your labels should then use that style so you won't have to manually set it every time, and you can add additional properties to your CSS file too. I learned how to use this recently and I find that it makes my code look a lot less messy.

Comment: You should use a style class instead, so that you can pick and choose which elements get the larger/smaller font...